# TensorFlow: Difference in performance of gather for int32 and int64 indices on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I run a small, test to evaluate the performance of several TF operations, and noticed an interesting phenomenon. On multiple machines, I consistently get better performance for operations using `int64` indices vs `int32` indices. For example, as below for `gather`, if `index_dtype` is `np.int32`, the operation is 2x slower than for `np.int64`.

My mini test consists of a graph of `gather` operations that run sequentially (the tuple ensures that there is a dependency on the output of the previous operation):

```
indices = np.asarray(indices, dtype=index_dtype)
params = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

op = tf.gather(params, indices)
for _ in range(num_ops):
    op = tf.gather(tf.tuple([params, op])[0], indices)
```

I run the graph multiple times and averaged the time (ignoring the first run).

Since, `int32` is the native int type for GPU computations, I would expect the opposite behavior. What could be the cause of such difference in performance?

Comment: one hypothesis -- GPU gather op requires gpu indices to be in host memory. When you int32 indicies, they get placed on GPU, and then executing the op requires the transfer of indices from GPU to CPU. There was something similar with dynamic_stitch, this issue shows how to do profiling for this case -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7251#issuecomment-277385212

Comment: Good catch, that could be it.